# Binary stream '238' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader

Tags: c#, memory, arrays, memorystream, binaryformatter

I was converting `ByteArray To Object` using the below code:

```
private static Object ByteArrayToObject(byte[] arrBytes)
{
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
    memStream.Write(arrBytes, 0, arrBytes.Length);
    memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    Object obj = (Object)binForm.Deserialize(memStream);
    return obj;
}
```

Suddenly it throws error as

> Binary stream '238' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible
>   causes are invalid stream or object version change between
>   serialization and deserialization.

What i have to do to get out of this error?

Comment: Where did this byte array come from? If it's not the result of *serializing* an object using `BinaryFormatter`, that would explain the problem.

Comment: The input byte array is the result of an encryption. I was trying to encrypt an object of a class

Comment: Well you need to decrypt it before you deserialize it then - it's as simple as that. (Personally I wouldn't use .NET binary serialization anyway, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Decryption also gives me a byte array, i have to get the object back from this array

Comment: Yes, so you call this code on the decrypted byte array. (Or better, skip the writing part and just create the stream with `new MemoryStream(arrBytes)`, but it's still basically the same...) If that's not working for you, please provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem - it may be the decryption which is failing.

Comment: Okey sir, Let me try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91349/discussion-between-un-lucky-and-jon-skeet).